# ASP.NET MVC jQuery Unobtrusive Validation to compare between two dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to validate `StartDate` and `EndDate` using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, such that the End Date must not be lesser than the Start Date. In my Model, I have defined the dates as follows:

```
public partial class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I have also created a View Model as follows:

```
public class CompareDateVM : IValidatableObject
{

    public MyModel myModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {

        if (myModel.EndDate < myModel.StartDate) {
            yield return
              new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "End Date cannot be lesser than Start Date.",
                                   memberNames: new[] { "EndDate" });
        }
    }
}
```

The server-side validation works and the error message is able to display in my View Page's `@Html.ValidationSummary(), but I am unable to get the validation working on the client-side.

```
@model CompareDateVM
<form asp-controller="AddDate" asp-action="Add" method="post">

    <label class="label">Start Date</label>
    <input type="date" asp-for="myModel.StartDate" />
    <span asp-validation-for="myModel.StartDate" class="validation"></span><br /><br />

    <label class="label">End Date</label>
    <input type="date"  asp-for="myModel.EndDate" />
    <!-- This is where the client side validation error message show up, but it does not appear-->
    <span asp-validation-for="myModel.EndDate" class="validation"></span>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Date" />
</form>
<!-- Server side validation works -->
<p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

How do I get `<span asp-validation-for="myModel.StartDate" class="validation"></span>` to show the error message on client side with jQuery Unobtrusive Validation?

Comment: I have answered your question and updated my answer a little bit now . Follow it as exactly as it was described. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: `IValidatableObject` does not give client side validation. For that you need a `ValidationAttribute` that iplmements `IClientModelValidator` (refer [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the custom unobtrusive validation in ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core MVC, you need to use `RemoteAttribute` as follows:

**Step1: Your Model class should be as follows:**

```
public partial class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote(action: "IsEndDateSmallerThanStartDate", controller: "Validation", AdditionalFields = nameof(StartDate), ErrorMessage = "End Date cannot be lesser than Start Date.")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

   // This is for server side protection
   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
       if (EndDate < StartDate)
       {
          yield return new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "End Date cannot be lesser than Start Date.", memberNames: new[] { "EndDate" });
       }
   }
}
```

**Step 2: Then in the Validation Controller:**

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsEndDateSmallerThanStartDate(DateTime endDate, DateTime startDate)
    { 
        bool isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate =  endDate > startDate;
        return Json(isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate); // if isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate variable value is true, that means validation is successful, if false that means validation fails.
    }
}
```

***Remember you don't need any ViewModel, so remove the ViewModel.***

**Step-3 : Then your cshtml file should be as follows:**

```
@model MyModel

<form asp-controller="AddDate" asp-action="Add" method="post">
    <!-- Server side validation works -->
    <p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>

    <label class="label">Start Date</label>
    <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="validation"></span><br /><br />

    <label class="label">End Date</label>
    <input asp-for="EndDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="validation"></span>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Date" />
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**Hope everything will now work as expected!**

Comment: Thanks, but my form doesn't seem to be submitting anymore.. it worked for a moment however, but the error showed up even when the end date was not lesser than the start date.

Comment: Wait I am checking it again.

Comment: It's working again, turns out i got the action and controller set wrongly. But the end date error still shows up even when its not lesser than the start date

Comment: I have updated the validation controller. Please check. Please debug the validation controller code and let me know the `isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate` variable value while endDate is greater than startDate.

Comment: The value of `isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate` is false

Comment: Yes! that means endDate is actually smaller than startDate in validation controller method. There is no wrong in my code. this is simple comparison. Check the endDate and startDate value on debug mode in validation controller method. May be endDate and startDate have been interchanged anywhere in your code. Please check it carefully.

Comment: It worked after switching the operator to `<` instead of `>` (which is what i wanted to compare), but I am not able to get the form to submit even though I corrected my date upon my second attempt.

Comment: I can assure you that there is no wrong in my code. So please check your code properly.

Comment: I have checked my code and I can confirm the logic from your code is correct. However, when the validation fails and I input the correct date on my second attempt, it does not validate anymore, and my form basically does not submit. Could this be because I have a view model? I need the view model as I have 2 List<object> that I need to populate my form for.

Comment: Add your Get and Post Method of the controller in the question please so that I can understand where the wrong actually lies.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me to figure my problem out. Here is my code snippet https://gist.github.com/iamhx/6fa25a4866ab2d6e2c76f284773c3f14

Comment: I asked you to remove the ViewModel but you didn't. You are passing LeaveApplicationVM object to the view but your remote attribute is on LeaveApplication, then how will it work properly?

Comment: like I said, I needed a view model to pre populate the `<select>` inputs, which is why I kept the viewmodel. So I can set the remote attribute on my viewmodel, instead of LeaveApplication?

Comment: Moreover no problem in my code for the solution of custom unobtrusive ajax validation. problem lies on your code.

Comment: Come on chat! I have sent you chat message

Comment: Please check the answer again. I have updated the model class for server side validation protection.